# A series of natural numbers is divided into groups

Tags: sequences-and-series

A series of natural numbers is divided into groups: $$(1),(2,3,4), (5,6,7,8,9,10,11), (12,13,......,26)$$ and so on.

The sum of numbers in $n^{th}$ group is $a.2^{2n-1}-(2n+b)2^{2n-1}+n+1$. Then find $a+b$

The main problem I am facing here is to find first term of $n^{th}$ group. Series for first term is like $1,2,5,12,27,...$ In this series I observed that difference of difference is in G.P. but don't know how to use this information.

Comment: Each value of $n$ gives you an equation in $a$ and $b$.  You already have four values of $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Let the first term of the $n^{th}$ group be $a_n$.

Then, as per your observation,
$$(a_{n+2}-a_{n+1})-(a_{n+1}-a_n)=2^n$$
or
$$a_{n+2}-2a_{n+1}+a_n=2^n$$

This is a linear non homogeneous recurrence relation, and on solving, you can express $a_n$ as a function of $n$.

Answer (score 2):

The leading term of $n$-th group is $2^{n}-n$ so the last term is $2^{n+1}-n-2$.

Hence, the sum is 
\begin{align*}
  & \quad \frac{1}{2} (2^{n+1}-n-2+2^{n}-n)(2^{n+1}-n-2-2^{n}+n+1) \\
  &= (3\cdot 2^{n-1}-n-1)(2^{n}-1) \\
  &= 3\cdot 2^{2n-1}-3\cdot 2^{n-1}-n\cdot 2^{n}+n+1 \\
  &= 3\cdot 2^{2n-1}-(2n+3) 2^{n-1}+n+1
\end{align*}